# Collections throughput issue

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a two different CosmosDB account for staging and production. I have an issue with the throughput I configured for collections.

In staging CosmosDB one of the collections have 4000 RU. In metrics, I can see that the provisioned throughput is similar to what I configured.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In production one of the collections have a different throughput rather than what I configured. The provisioned throughput is 12000 RU and in metrics what I can see is 1200 RU. It seems the provisioned throughput is divided by 10.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The only difference what I can see is the read and write location of the CosmosDB accounts. I don't have a much idea about this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Is the collection partitioned?

If it is then the throughput is divided evenly between the partitions e.g. if you provision 12000 RU/s for the whole collection and there are 10 partitions your throughput per partition will be 12000/10 = 1200 RU/s.

A message should be displayed at the top of the page to say:

Collection {NAME} has 10 partition key ranges. Provisioned throughput is evenly distributed across these partitions (1200 RU/s per partition).